# Scatter points on subplot edge within Gridspec get clipped

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I define a Gridspec like so:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
gs = grd.GridSpec(2, 1, wspace=0, hspace=0, height_ratios=[0.5, 0.5])

first = plt.subplot(gs[0])
second = plt.subplot(gs[1])

first.set_ylim(5, 10)
first.set_xlim(0, 10)
second.set_ylim(0, 5)
second.set_xlim(0, 10)
```

and then plot a point on the edge of one of the subplots that share a border,

```
first.scatter(5, 5)
plt.show()
```

the point gets clipped on the border and only the top half of the scatter circle is displayed. Is there a way for the point to show up across the border? (Adding `clip_on=False` doesn't affect the outcome).

A partial solution is to set `second.patch.set_alpha(0)` so that the second half of the scatter point appears. The issue with this is that in my original plot, each subplot has a background color set with

```
second.axhspan(*second.get_ylim(), facecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
```

and so even if I set the axes background to transparent with `second.patch.set_alpha(0)`, the overlapping scatter point will now have half of it be covered in a 0.5 alpha color, which I don't want. Put simply, I want the scatter points to have zorder higher than anything else, including surrounding subplots.

The only other solution I've thought of (if there's truly no easy way to do this), would be to overlay a transparent axes over the entire figure, and plot my scatter points there. The reason I don't want to do that is because in reality, my Gridspec is very complicated and combines several non-linear y-axes, and thus mapping points from absolute coordinates to relative figure coordinates would be quite difficult.

Comment: Have no answer, but one hint: the scale of your upper x-axis disturbs on the y-axis with a half overwritten `0`. Perhaps you'd do better with `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize=(15,8), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0, 'hspace': 0})`.

Comment: @SpghttCd Thank you for your comment. Like i mentioned in my post, my actual plot is a lot more complicated, and I am fully aware of and have accounted for/fixed all overlapping features. I didn't bother doing so in the snippet i posted because it is not relevant to my question and i wanted to post the smallest bit of code possible to reproduce my situation.

Comment: Zorder only applies to the axes you are drawing in.  You can determine the order axes will be draw in by adding them to the figure in the order you want.  But if you have two axes and you want unclipped markers from either of them to be drawn last, I don’t think that is possible.

Comment: ok so there's no way to do this then? I suppose I could define my own custom scale and do away with the subplots, but there's very little documentation on defining a custom y-scale

Comment: Why not plot all points in all axes, such that they will appear in each of them?

Comment: I would just clip the points and adjust my x/y limits so they are shown.  I’m not sure what the goal of having them overhang the plot is.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I suspect the idea is to create a plot consisting of two or more (linear?) ranges but each with different scale, e.g. lower subplot goes from 0 to 5, upper subplot from 5 to 100. Points which appear at the edge of one of the ranges should then not be clipped.

Comment: I see. I’d just make a scale.  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale

Comment: That's exactly right. I have a plot with 4 separate subscales, 3 of which are linear and one of which is logarithmic. So i can't just display the points on all scales because the ones close to the edge will not be perfectly overlaid since the scales are so drastically different. I tried defining my own scale but it was a mess. I don't think it handles non-invertible piece-wise functions very well. What i ended up doing what transforming my data myself and then using the transformation to set ytick labels properly and essentially "lie" to my viewer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def forward(a):
    x = a
    ind = np.where(a>5)[0]
    x[ind] = (x[ind] - 5)*5/95 + 5
    return x


def inverse(a):
    x = a
    ind = np.where(a>5)[0]
    x[ind] = (x[ind] - 5) * 95 / 5 + 5
    return x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
x = t * 10

ax.plot(t, x, 'd', ms=3)

ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
ax.set_yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Damn this is really good. This was my first attempt as well (using forward and inverse functions), but my functions were far too complicated to bother computing inverses. Thank you though, I will save this for future reference!

Comment: The lazy way is to create a big lookup table and interpolate in both the forward ind inverse function